# Asp.Net MVC application does not update files on web host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm developing an MVC 2 application and have it on a web host. It works fine, but the strange thing is that when I update files, the updates don't "take". I can even delete an entire Controller file (just for testing the update problem), and it doesn't matter. I can still go to that page on the live site. That shouldn't be possible, but apparently it does, as if the Controller was still there.

The only way I can update the site at the moment is by deleting every single file on the server, and then upload the entire site again. Then (strangely) it works, and the updates take.

Does anyone have any experience with similar problems and ideas for how to solve it? BTW, I have asked the support at the web host, but unfortunately they rarely have any answers for anything but the simplest problems, so I thought I might be better off asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit a controller file, then you need to recompile it and deploy the .dll file, there is no need to even bother hosting the controller files.

You can edit the views freely though.